# Using cursors sql?

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor, sql-scripts

I am doing a project using sql cursors, for one cursor i want to loop through a dataset of Company ids.

How would you use logic such as

1. Tables without CompanyID need all data copying.
2. Always copy data where CompanyID = 0

How would you perform this is a while loop of a cursor.

I have been looking at this tutorial

http://examplesql.com/sqlserver-transact-t-sql/how-to-loop-using-sql-server-cursor-fetch-fast_forward/

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish? Are you sure a cursor based approach is needed?

Comment: Use of cursor must be rare when you write a script. Think always about set of data.

Comment: Are you aware that you can perform updates on joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one it's always recommended in all cases to absolutely avoid the use of cursors. They are known to experience very poor performance issues and 95% of the time it's possible to perform the necessary function with set-based logic.

To solve this particular problem using psuedo would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable
SELECT CompanyID, SomeDataColumn
FROM SourceTable
WHERE ISNULL(CompanyID, 0) = 0
```

Comment: It is not me choosing the cursor approach my boss has told me to use them, thanks for your solution it looks like what i need